# API design questions for an asynchronous socket

Tags: c++, networking

I'm writing a thread-safe asynchronous networking library.

I'm contemplating about the API design. The user of the library would like to write as few code as possible.

Which is semantically more correct?

**1.**

a) `open()` - synchronous, opens the socket.

b) `connect(IP, port)` - asynchronous, connects the socket.

c) `close()` - synchronous, closes the socket.

**2.**

a) `open(IP, port)` - asynchronous, opens and connects the socket.

b) `close()` - synchronous, closes the socket.

Is it semantically correct to treat the 'opened' state as the 'connected' state. This differs from low-level networking libraries where 'opened' and 'connected' are separate states.

Also, in case of an error (on opening, connecting, reading, writing), should the socket perform the cleanup of resources and return itself to the closed state? Alternatively, should the socket go into the 'error' state and require the user of the library to perform `close()`.

Comment: Have you had a look at Boost.Asio?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I have. It lacks thread-safety (for example having to be extra careful not to enqueue multiple asychronous reads/writes at a time) and proper lifetime management for inter-related objects (for example an asio::io_service being able to destruct before a socket using it destructs). In fact this library is a wrapper around Asio. My question was really about semantics here.